# '.' is not recognised as internal or external command on windows?

Tags: reactjs, npm

i have the line below in the package.json file.

```
"start:setup": "./start-setup.sh",
```

and from windows command prompt i run the command npm run start:setup

and i get this error..

'.' is not recognised as an internal or external command....

**what i have tried?**
i tried the above command on gitbash and didnt work.

i changed this

```
"start:setup": "./start-setup.sh",
 to
 "start:setup": "sh start-setup.sh",
```

and error sh is not an external or internal command is thrown

Could someone help me fix this. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`.sh` is a Linux shell file.
Windows doesn't process such files by default.
If you want, you could try installing bash for windows.